# Android - Parsing a JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON string

```
    try {
        String candyJson = "{\"candies\":[ {\"name\":\"Jelly Beans\", \"count\":10}, {\"name\":\"Butterscotch\", \"count\":6}]}";
        JSONObject candiesJSONobject = new JSONObject(candyJson);
        JSONArray candiesJSONarray = candiesJSONobject.getJSONArray("candies");
        Log.v("JSONObject", candiesJSONarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("MYAPP", e.toString());
    }
```

The code works fine in this state without catching any exception and prints JSONObject name in the Android Log.

**However** when I don't try to catch the exception as shown in the following example:

```
        String candyJson = "{\"candies\":[ {\"name\":\"Jelly Beans\", \"count\":10}, {\"name\":\"Butterscotch\", \"count\":6}]}";
        JSONObject candiesJSONobject = new JSONObject(candyJson);
        JSONArray candiesJSONarray = candiesJSONobject.getJSONArray("candies");
        Log.v("JSONObject", candiesJSONarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
```

Android Studio gives me unhandled exception error on all JSON methods. Is it necessary to catch JSONException when parsing a JSON or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Read `Exception handling` first.

Comment: your json is not well formed . Invalid json . http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: The JSON String is working fine. I'm using backslashes for escaping quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Java feature actually :-) Please read more about it [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

The idea is that - if a method states that it will throw an (non-Runtime) Exception, all the calls of that method are **required** to catch this exception, **just in case**.

It does not mean that you are getting this exception in your code, you can only see that when you actually run it. But Java requires you to be prepared for a situation where such exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That link is very helpful!

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark the answer as correct :-)

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer. Will do it asap.

Comment: Well here the problem is that the buildin version of org.json is outdated. JSONException should not be Checked Exception. 
There is no added value in having to try catch everything, it make the code unreadable.
In newer versions of org.json (stleary/JSON-java) JSONException extends RuntimeException. Unfortunately due to naming conflict we can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you're working with the org.json... json objects, yes most of their methods do throw exceptions that you must catch and handle.

However if you don't want to handle each exception on it's own i suggest you create a json utils class that will handle those things for you.

For example for the JSONObject constructor you can make your own method like so

```
    public static JSONObject createObjectFromString(String objectString) {
    try {
        return new JSONObject(objectString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.e("MYAPP", e.toString());
    }
}
```

and just reuse this method when you want to create a new json object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually if any method is throwing Exception you need to catch that Exception.
This is called as **Checked Exceptions** or **Compile Time Exceptions**.

In your case methods like

```
JsonArray getJsonArray(String name)
```

or

```
JsonObject getJsonObject(String name)
```

check here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonArray-java.lang.String-

are throwing `ClassCastException` So you either catch it or throw the exception.
Throwing Exception will lead to crash the app, So better Catch it.

Answer (score 0):

If any method throws checked Exception, then caller can either handle this exception by catching it or can re throw it by declaring another throws clause in method declaration.

This is the reason Android Studio is showing unhandled exception error.